# Rasa NLU model loading takes significant amount of time

Tags: performance, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am using **rasa nlu** alone for my usecase. I am training the rasa model using rasa.nlu.model.Trainer and loading the model using rasa.nlu.model.Interpreter. I have 5+ different nlu models.

I have below issues,

1. Model loading takes nearly 35 to 40 secs. So for 5 models, its 200 secs. I would like to load model faster.
2. So, i planned to dump using pickle. And tried to load. In that case i am getting the following error.

   > TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

i am using Rasa 1.5.3.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Seeni here is a related question on SO that addresses a similar query.
In summary, `supervised_embeddings` pipeline should take the least amount of time to load up your trained models.